# What are the side effects of caching bridged UIViews?

Tags: swift, react-native

I have a React Native app and a component that I need to build in Swift. I've bridged a `UIView` and it's working great.

The `view` method in `RCTViewManager` says, `The view module MUST NOT cache the returned view.` I chose to cache my view since I have items that are expensive to remake. I encountered a couple of layout glitches which I fixed by overriding `layoutSubviews` and `removeFromSuperview` in the `UIView`.

I can't find any memory leaks or other issues. What am I risking by leaving my UIView as being cached rather than remade?

Comment: Is there any part of the view that can be cached? Can you cache it's layer, or anything else expensive to create?

Comment: I could easily wrap my existing, cached UIView in a new UIView each time it wants one. I'm trying to figure out what pitfalls caching has so that I don't accidentally still have them as I try to cache other things.